# Taxes on PayPal submit

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using a php file to send data of the user (that I have got from a previous form of my website) to PayPal. All works except the "Tax" field.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, my code is:

```
// by code: querystring = ?business=blabla&item_name=bla.... (all this works)
if ($country_data['extra_tax'] != '0.00')
   $querystring .= "tax=".urlencode($country_data['extra_tax'])."&";
// and more and more code until redirect to paypal
```

And on the IPN:

```
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
```

But it doesn't charge even on the paypal website, so the tax is not reaching IPN. Must be on my petition on the querystring, but don't know why.

How I said, the rest of the code works, but tax not.

Greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Website Payments Standard, but what type of button are you using?  Some buttons do not allow for tax or shipping?  Are you trying to have tax for the entire cart or just one item?  Try using the variable `tax_cart`.

Comment: The button are "_xclick" type. Until monday I can't test it, but i will comment my results then.

Comment: Can you provide the entire string that you are sending over to PayPal.  (variables and values)

Comment: ?business=info%40example.com&item_name=Monocaja+Tapas&amount=29.95&tax=&custom=2%7Cm-11%7C94%2C84%2C64%2C66%2C13%2C8%2C7%2C29&cmd=_xclick¤cy_code=EUR&bn=button_BuyNow_WPS_ES&address=ddvcxvcx&city=ddd&country=Eslovenia&zip=dd&first_name=dd&last_name=dd&email=javier%40myemail.es&state=dd&on0=gi&os0=0&on1=at&os1=&on2=tx&os2=&on3=ni&os3=70000000B&on4=ic&os4=8&on5=dt&os5=Hi%2C+how+are+you%3F&return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fthank-you%2F&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%3Fcancel%3D1¬ify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-ipn.php

Comment: (I replace the personal data) How I said, the tax are not adding from the form, so it's not reaching the "to-paypal" script:

<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="'.$country_data['extra_tax'].'" />

(Neither tax_cart)